# Routes doesn't connect the right controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to load the VideoController.php when url.com/video/ is called.
Here is a piece of code from my routes.php

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

  $routes->connect('/video/*', ['controller' => 'Video', 'action' => 'display']); 
  ...
  $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

The result is '404 not found'

**EDIT:**

Inside Router::scope I have also this piece of code:

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
```

When I change the Pages value into Video, the VideoController is called. So how come when I change the '/' into '/video/*' it doesn't work?

Maybe it's something with the scope function parameters?

Comment: isn't your controller named "videos" in plural?

Comment: No, it's the way I wrote it above

Comment: Are you have 'display' action inside VideoController?

Comment: Yes I did implement the display method.

Comment: btw. cake convention is to use lower case first letter of controller name

Comment: @Sojtin the 3 controllers that come with basic cakephp projects are "AppController", "ErrorController" and "PagesController" so I followed it and create the "VideoController"

Comment: @ImriPersiado i mean in url statement `['controller' => 'pages' ...]` not `['controller' => 'Pages'...]`

Comment: @Sojtin I accept your comment, just saying that this is not custom code. that's how it comes with the cakePHP project.

Comment: @ImriPersiado i see now, it's true for 3.x version.

Comment: anything else works for you? the route depends also on the web server configuration. so wonder if it's just that controller that doesn't work.

Comment: Try to post the output of `bin/cake routes` from the shell.

Comment: @SelaYair The code I added above in the edit section is working, when I submit this url: url.com/ the proper(Pages) controller is called, and if I change the value Pages to Video in this line it calls the Video controller.

Comment: @Spriz Can you give me more details about what you want me to do? I'm not sure what do I need to do.

Comment: @ImriPersiado Run the command `bin/cake routes` from your shell/cmd and post the output to eg. gist.github.com

Comment: @Spriz Here is the result: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1aaf30ed0775c0aec8a970a8c93bbf54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling URL rewriting from the httpd.config file solved the problem.
[cakephp documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html)